# Converting IRandomAccessStream to RandomAccessStreamReference C#

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

i am converting IRandomAccessStream to RandomAccessStreamReference in this below code, but when i see results there is no image for share. how can i handle this?

```
if (imageFile != null)
{
    using (IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await util.imageFile.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read))
    {
        this.imageStreamRef = RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromFile(imageFile);
        this.dataPackageThumbnail = this.imageStreamRef;
        //  this.imageStream = await util.imageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
        await fileStream.FlushAsync();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.streams.irandomaccessstream

try to reset the stream (Seek).